# How to submit multiple objects in JSON data as request body in Apache CXF jax-rs (REST)

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf

I am using Apache-CXF for creating REST web services and trying to do an on a name in the db.

Server:
This is my method, which is expected to get json data.

```
@PUT
@Path("/name/")
@Consumes("multipart/mixed")
@Produces("application/json")   
public NameTO updateName(@Multipart (value = "accountIdentifier", 
type =  "application/json")AccountIdentifier accountIdentifier, 
@Multipart (value = "name", type = "application/json")NameTO nameTO)
{
//      do business logic over here
    return nameTO;
}
```

Client: I am using firefox REST plugin for submitting request: Using REST client, I have posted following json as request body:

```
{{  "accountIdentifier": {"accountNo":"12345","division":"10","portfolio":"OT","channel": "MB"}} ,
{"name": { "firstName" : "Test", "middleInitial" : "R", "lastName" : "Test123", "suffix" : "Mr", "fullName" : "Test Test123"}}}
```

I have set following content-type in the Rest Client:

Content-Type: multipart/mixed

I get the following exception:

> 2012-12-10 14:23:54 WebApplicationExceptionMapper.java:toResponse
>   [WARN] javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException:
>   org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Couldn't determine the boundary from
>   the message!

Any sample example where I could pass multiple objects in Json Request payload to the Rest Service and the changes to be done in the service side would be helpful.